# Name convention for keys in app.config

Tags: .net

What is the name convention for keys in app.config?
[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) doesn't include it.

Example:

```
 <add key="enablemail" value="true" />
```

Or

```
 <add key="EnableMail" value="true" />
```

Or

```
 <add key="enableMail" value="true" />
```

Comment: Whichever you prefer is fine.  And they don't all have to follow the same convention.  Personally I prefer the second one.  In general, name something by what it is intuitively called.  From there the rest is just details and semantics.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There isn't an established convention that I know of and I read the BCL guidelines, which should be your first stop for .NET style questions-- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229042.aspx

Also, there is no namespacing for appSettings and libraries and the main app can share app settings, so library authors have sometimes included ad-hoc namespacing conventions, e.g.

```
 <add key="myApp:enableMail" value="true" />
 <add key="someLibrary:enableMail" value="true" />
```

I usually write utility code for referring to a key so that most of the time I'm calling public bool getIsEmailEnabled() instead of writing a string literal in multiple places in the application.